# Creating subplots using R base

Tags: r, plot

This [link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/egg/vignettes/Ecosystem.html) shows good examples of creating side-by-side plots using several packages. However, I would like to create a (4 x 1) plot in R using base functions only.

Here is what I have tried:

```
par(mar=c(0.2, 0.2, 0.7, 0.7), mfrow=c(4,1), oma = c(4, 4, 0.2, 0.2))
# Plot 1
plot(my_data$date, my_data$col1, type="l", col = "red", ylab = expression("my_legend"^{-5}), xlab = "", xaxt="nan", lwd = 1)
lines(my_data$date, my_data$col2, type="l", col = "blue", lwd = 1)
legend(14, 20, legend=c("Line 1", "Line 2"), col=c("red", "blue"), lty=1:2, cex=0.8)
# Plot 2
plot(my_data$date, my_data$col3, type="l", col = "magenta",xlab = "", xaxt = "nan", ylab = expression("my_legend"^{2}))
lines(my_data$date, my_data$col4, type="l", col = "green")
legend(14, 20, legend=c("Line 3", "Line 5"), col=c("orange", "yellow"), lty=1:2, cex=0.8)
# Plot 3
plot(my_data$date, my_data$col5, type="l", col = "olivedrab2",xlab = "", xaxt = "nan", ylab = expression("my_legend"^{8}))
# Plot 4
plot(my_data$date, my_data$col6, type="l", col = "sandybrown", xlab = "Time (3 May 1994)", ylab = expression("my_legend"^{7}))
```

I want y-axes titles (all four plots) and a common x-axis title (plot 4).
That is, y-axis title (here, plot 1) is not displayed, neither x-axis title (plot 4) and legends (inside plot 1) are shown. Could someone help me to understand why?

Comment: Since you do not provide your data,  we cannot run your code.

Answer (score 1):

You might find this link useful.

https://stevencarlislewalker.wordpress.com/2012/06/28/overall-axis-labels-with-mfrow/

I'll copy the code here in case the link dies, but you should read his post.  As of 2019 it was still available.  Idea is to plot without axes using `xaxt='n'` and `yaxt='n'` then use `mtext` to label the 'overall' axes by annotating the margins of the plot.

I still think ggplot offers you more capability, perhaps your company doesn't allow you to install it?

```
# thanks to 
# https://stevencarlislewalker.wordpress.com/2012/06/28/overall-axis-labels-with-mfrow/
par(mfrow = c(2, 2)) # 2-by-2 grid of plots
par(oma = c(4, 4, 0, 0)) # make room (i.e. the 4's) for the overall x and y axis titles
par(mar = c(2, 2, 1, 1)) # make the plots be closer together

# now plot the graphs with the appropriate axes removed (via xaxt and yaxt),
# remove axis labels (so that they are not redundant with overall labels,
# and set some other nice choices for graphics parameters
plot(runif(10), xlab = '', ylab = '', xaxt = 'n', las = 1, ylim = c(0, 1))
plot(runif(10), xlab = '', ylab = '', xaxt = 'n', yaxt = 'n', ylim = c(0, 1))
plot(runif(10), xlab = '', ylab = '', las = 1, ylim = c(0, 1))
plot(runif(10), xlab = '', ylab = '', yaxt = 'n', ylim = c(0, 1))

# print the overall labels
mtext('x-axis title', side = 1, outer = TRUE, line = 2)
mtext('y-axis title', side = 2, outer = TRUE, line = 2)
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried your code, which gives one x- and y-axis. However, I need to have to separate y-axis for each column. I have added some sample data and desired result.

Comment: The idea was to show you techniques that would point you in the right direction rather than to do all your thinking for you.  Change the mfrow parameter to four rows and one column, and then remove the `yaxt='n'` parameters in the second and fourth and you should be closer to you what you want.  Personally, I think using  `ggplot` presents a more coherent appearance, and if for some reason you _must_ use base only, it would be helpful to know the constraints that make this so.